# When searching on our website through Algolia it shows max. 5 results. How can I change the limit?

Tags: search, algolia

On our website www.betconstruct.com we use algolia as our search engine!

The results are max 5 pages.

How can I increase the limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `200 <= hitsPerPage < 250`, this is expected. Indeed, Algolia limits the amount of results you can retrieve to [the first 1000 relevant results](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/how-can-i-retrieve-all-the-records-in-my-index).

> Algolia limits the maximum number of search results to 1000 for a question of performance, but also to limit the access to your catalogue in case security matters to you.
>   If you want to retrieve more than 1000 objects, you can use our [Browse](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#browse-all-index-content) method implemented in all our API clients. This method supports most of the search parameters, which allows you to retrieve results beyond this limit.
>   Learn how to do in our [Infinite Scroll Instant Search](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/infinite-scroll#searching-vs-browsing)

Diplaying more than 1000 search results is usually not necessary though.
Neither [Google](https://www.google.fr/#q=te&start=140)
nor [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/?page=15&keywords=te) display a `Last` button in their pagination, and both limit the number of results to a reasonable amount.